# Как использовать несколько шапок файлов в PHPStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains

Доброго времени суток!

Коллеги, подскажите, каким образом можно использовать несколько шаблонов шапок файлов? Имеется ввиду шапка с комментариями.

```
 /**
  * Created by PhpStorm.
  * User: User
  * Date: 29.08.14
  * Time: 1:48
  */
```

Мне это нужно для прозрачного переключения копирайтов для разных проектов.

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии 11, PhpStorm идет в комплекте c плагином [Copyright](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/copyright.html), специально предназначенным для этих целей.

[image: Copyright Profiles]

Сначала необходимо создать профили в Settings > Editor > Copyright > Copyright Profiles, потом можно установить один из них по-умолчанию или распределить их по соответствующим Scopes.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плагин позволяет настраивать стиль комментариев, их расположение в файле, автоматически обновлять копирайт блоки при наличии ключевого слова и др. Туториал на английском языке доступен [в блоге](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/01/managing-copyright-notices-in-phpstorm/) JetBrains.

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то, что было нужно!)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял, то идём:
Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates. В правом окне выбираем закладку Includes, смотрим шаблон "PHP File Header" и создаем по его образу и подобию свои шаблоны "шапок".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я имел ввиду создание дополнительных шаблонов. Т.к. постоянно изменять шаблоны не особо удобно.

Comment: @BrusSENS Там сверху есть несколько кнопок. Среди них кнопка для создания нового шаблона и копирование, т.е. создание из существующего.

Comment: Создать я создал, с этим проблем нет, но вот каким образом заставить при создании, например, php файла использовать именно этот шаблон, вот я о чём. Прошу прощения, если не донёс эту суть в вопросе.

Comment: @BrusSENS Переходите на закладку "Files" и, например, в шаблоне PHP Class для одного проекта подключаете шапку "Header for Apple.php", для другого - "Header for Microsoft.php" и т.д. То есть, изменяете следующий код: `#parse("PHP File Header.php")`

Comment: да, это я делал. Получается, что нужно будет создать несколько одинаковых типов файлов и при создании файла выбирать, например "Php File Type1"? Если так, то конечно жаль, я думал можно привязать к проекту.